# What is the best practice to maintain multiple versions of cross-compile toolchains

Tags: arm, cross-compiling, embedded-linux, toolchain

I did `apt-get install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi` to install cross-compile toolchain for arm. This installed version 4.7 for me. Later I had to install at least version 5 to compile a specific version of kernel, so I did `apt-get install gcc-5-arm-linux-gnueabi` . To switch between the above 2 versions of each of the included binaries, I had to install setup for `update-alternatives`.

Now again I am facing a situation where I have to do install version 7 of toolchain. I have downloaded the package from linaro website ([link](https://releases.linaro.org/components/toolchain/binaries/)) which is a tar package. Now it has around 20 binaries and I believe all of them should be installed together (i.e. -gcc, -g++, -as, etc should be default from this package together). Now I really don't want to install `update-alternatives` for each of them one by one. Neither do I put all of them in the `/usr/bin` folder and overwrite the other 2 versions of binaries.

What is the best practice to maintain all 3 toolchain environments together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you can keep your toolchains in separate directories (e.g. /usr/bin/{v4, v6, v7}. Then, you can either have your shell's `$PATH` include those directories directly, or (in the case of the Linux kernel and many other projects), just set the `CROSS_COMPILE` environment variable as you build.

For example, to build with v6:

```
make CROSS_COMPILE=/usr/bin/v6/arm-gnueabi-
```

And v7:

```
make CROSS_COMPILE=/usr/bin/v7/arm-gnuabi-
```

Typically, one wouldn't make subdirectories within `/usr/bin`, so maybe you'd want to install the toolchains somewhere like `/opt/arm-toolchains/vN/`.